# N, M are normal subgroups of G

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

We know that in $G$ with $(gh)^5=g^{5}h^{5}$
Given that $N=\{ g|g^5=e \}$, $M=\{ g^5 \}$ are normal subgroups of G. Prove that $N∩M= \{ e \}$.

Ugh I'm clueless, I do know how to prove that $NM$ is a normal subgroup under this construction. But that's basically it.

Comment: You should add some other assumption or else the statement is absurd

Comment: If $N$ and $M$ are both equal to $G$, and $G$ contains more than one element, then what you claim definitely won't be the case.

Comment: You were right, I added more details to the question. I thought I didn't need all the information

Comment: It's very hard to understand your question's wording:(1) do you mean that $\;(gh)^5=g^5h^5\;$ for *all* the elements in the groups or only for two of them? (2) Is $\;N\;$ defined to be the set of all elements that rised to the fifth power are the unit, or is it the subgroup *generated* by these elements? (3) Is $\;M\;$ the subgroup generated by all the fifth powers of elements in $\;G\;$ ? Excuse me, but this is a very poorly written question.

Comment: @joanpemo I'm riding on my bike so sorry for that:/ and yes! You are right!

Comment: @Bahbi I think we all could have waited for you to arrive to your destination to write your question in a reasonable way...and stop writing while riding a bike, lest you'll break your head.

Comment: This is not a badly written question.  Don't be discouraged by all these comments.   You were just trying to find the minimal hypotheses to make your assertion hold.  You are learning in the process. But that is what we are there for.

Answer (score 1):

I'm going to interpret your question as:

> Let $G$ be a group such that $(gh)^5=g^5h^5$ for all $g,h\in G$.  Then $\phi\;\colon\; g\mapsto g^5$ is a homomorphism, so 
>   $$
> N=\ker\phi=\{g\in G\;\colon\;g^5=e\}
> $$
>   is a normal subgroup of $G$.  Let $M=\left<g^5|g\in G\right>$ be subgroup of $G$ generated by all fifth powers of group elements $g$.  Suppose that $M$ is a normal subgroup of $G$.  Then $N\cap M=\{e\}$.

This is false.  For example, take $G=\mathbb Z/25\mathbb Z$.  Then $G$ is abelian, so in particular the identity $(gh)^5=g^5h^5$ holds and all subgroups of $G$ are normal subgroups.  But then $N=M=5\mathbb Z/25\mathbb Z$, so $N\cap M\ne\{e\}$.

Answer (score 0):

This is not true. If you take an commutative group and a proper non trivial subgroup then the intersection will remain the proper nontrivial subgroup.

Answer (score 0):

The statement is false without other hypotheses, infact: take $G=\mathbb{Z}$, and $M=\langle2\rangle$, $N=\langle4\rangle$, then $M\cap N=\langle4\rangle$.